# Using regex, get values and create dictionary

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, findall, python-re

First time posting an ongoing learning about Python.

Currently, I'm stuck with a very simple thing: I've a router's output - a list called "interfaces" - which, when printed, looks like this:

```
set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family inet address 192.168.15.66/24
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family inet dhcp
set interfaces ge-0/0/2 unit 0 family inet address 1.1.1.1/30
set interfaces ge-0/0/2 unit 0 family inet address 192.168.99.1/30
```

Using re module (findall), I'm finding and matching some keywords that I need, like this:

```
pattern1 = re.compile(r'ge.{1,7}')
pattern2 = re.compile(r'dhcp')
matched1 = pattern1.findall(interfaces)
matched2 = pattern2.findall(interfaces)
```

At this point, question is: If the line(?) of this router output contains the word "dhcp", I would like to save/store that value and grab the interface name/number too. In the example above, the interface cointaining "dhcp" is 'ge-0/0/1'. Do you guys have an idea if i'm going on the right path?

- Is the model (get two regex) useful, to then merge both value into a dictionary, to then print using return?
- How can I parse the rest of router code lines, to look for this "dhcp" value and then if no match can return a "none" or "not present" output?

Expected output will look like this (I'm using "return tabulate" to print the output):

```
| interface   | service    |
|-------------+------------|
| ge-0/0/0    |  none      | 
| ge-0/0/1    |  dhcp      | 
| ge-0/0/2    |  none      |
```

Any guidance, will be welcomed.
Thanks.

---

EDIT: Thanks both for your answers so far. I'm adding more info since probably is key.
The way I get that router output is using SaltStack integrated modules. I'm running that python file from the Salt Master, using the following syntax:

```
interfaces = __salt__['net.cli']('show configuration interfaces | display set', format='xml')['out']['show configuration interfaces | display set']
```

I sincerely hope that output is in fact a list.

In the meantime, I did another try using the following below:

```
def dhcp():

interfaces = __salt__['net.cli']('show configuration interfaces | display set', format='xml')['out']['show configuration interfaces | display set']

pattern = re.findall(r'ge.{1,7}', interfaces)
pattern1 = re.findall(r'dhcp', interfaces)

return pattern, pattern1
```

The output was this:

```
outright ~  sudo salt 'vsrx1' red.dhcp
vsrx1:
 |_
   - ge-0/0/0 
   - ge-0/0/0 
   - ge-0/0/0 
   - ge-0/0/0 
   - ge-0/0/1 
   - ge-0/0/2 
   - ge-0/0/2 
 |_
   - dhcp
```

Printing the list alone (using --> return("List is: " + str(pattern)) )

```
 outright ~  sudo salt 'vsrx1' red.dhcp
 vsrx1:
 List is: ['ge-0/0/0 ', 'ge-0/0/0 ', 'ge-0/0/0 ', 'ge-0/0/0 ', 'ge-0/0/1 ', 'ge-0/0/2 ', 'ge-0/0/2 ']
```

I do apologies if the way to express the issue is technically poor. I'm still learning the terminology in general.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to me that you are on the right track. Here is my interpretation of what I think you are asking for. Hope this helps. 
Note: I did this through my phone, so please excuse incorrect indentations

```
import re

s = ["set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family inet address 192.168.15.66/24",
"set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family inet dhcp", "set interfaces ge-0/0/2 unit 0 family inet address 1.1.1.1/30", 
"set interfaces ge-0/0/2 unit 0 family inet address 192.168.99.1/30"]

print("interfaces | services")
mydict ={}
def parse_addresses():
    for i in s:
            interface = re.search(r"ge.{1,7}", i)
            if "dhcp" in i:
                service = "dhcp"
                mydict.setdefault("router",{interface.group(): service})
            else:
                service = "None"
            print(f"{interface.group()} | {service}")
    if bool(mydict):
        return mydict
    return "None"

print(parse_addresses())
```

Comment: Thanks, Victor. I added more information to avoid confusions about the source of the information. Hopefully you have another point of view with it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you get the router's output. But this should work 
If your data is in this form

```
interface_list = ['set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family inet address 192.168.15.66/24',
'set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family inet dhcp',
'set interfaces ge-0/0/2 unit 0 family inet address 1.1.1.1/30',
'set interfaces ge-0/0/2 unit 0 family inet address 192.168.99.1/30']
```

Then

```
interface_dict = {}
```

```
for element in interface_list:
    element_list = element.split(" ")
    if element_list[7] =='dhcp':
        interface_dict[element_list[2]] = 'dhcp'
    else:
        interface_dict[element_list[2]] = 'none'
```

```
print(interface_dict)
```

will give you

```
{'ge-0/0/0': 'none', 'ge-0/0/1': 'dhcp', 'ge-0/0/2': 'none'}
```

You can then change the dictionary to the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.Series(interface_dict).to_frame().reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'interface', 0:'service'})
```

```
df 
    interface   service
0   ge-0/0/0    none
1   ge-0/0/1    dhcp
2   ge-0/0/2    none
```

Comment: Thanks, @pi_pascal , I'll try that and I come back with the results!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about Pandas. I left it for a bit, trying to first fix the "merge" of the tables and create the dictionary that I need. Info about router's output was added. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who viewed and oriented me in several possible directions.
I'm answering to my own question (90% at least). My final script follows (And yes, I know that my code can be 100% improved, but is what I did to reach my goal):

def final():

```
interfaces = []
output_table1 = []
output_table2 = []

interfaces = __salt__['net.cli']('show configuration interfaces | display set', format='xml')['out']['show configuration interfaces | display set']

# Saving output into a file for further use
with open("/srv/salt/_modules/aaa.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(interfaces)

# Regex patterns to match things
regex1 = re.compile(r'(ge.{1,7}.{7}).*?(?=sampling)')
match_reg1 = regex1.finditer(interfaces)

regex2 = re.compile(r'ge.{1,7}.{7}')
match_reg2 = regex2.finditer(interfaces)


# IF stataments and FOR, to match and append items
if match_reg1:
    output_table1.insert(0, "Sampled interfaces")
    for match1 in match_reg1:
        output_table1.append(match1.group(1))

if match_reg2:
    output_table2.insert(0, "Not sampled interfaces")
    for match2 in match_reg2:
        output_table2.append(match2.group())

# Differences between two tables: 
difference_list = []
for item in output_table2:
    if item not in output_table1:
        difference_list.append(item)

final = []
final.insert(0, "To enable sampling, insert the following on target device")
for line in difference_list:
    final.append("set interfaces " + line + "family inet sampling [input/output]")

return output_table1, difference_list, final
```

After above, my output was:

```
terminal# sudo salt 'vsrx1' red.final
vsrx1:
|_
  - Sampled interfaces
  - ge-0/0/1 unit 0 
  - ge-0/0/1 unit 0 
|_
  - Not sampled interfaces
  - ge-0/0/0 descrip
  - ge-0/0/0 unit 0 
  - ge-0/0/2 unit 0 
  - ge-0/0/2 unit 0 
|_
  - To enable sampling, insert the following on target device
  - set interfaces Not sampled interfacesfamily inet sampling [input/output]
  - set interfaces ge-0/0/0 descripfamily inet sampling [input/output]
  - set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family inet sampling [input/output]
  - set interfaces ge-0/0/2 unit 0 family inet sampling [input/output]
  - set interfaces ge-0/0/2 unit 0 family inet sampling [input/output]
```

Please remember that I'm using Saltstack proxy minions to pull information from that Juniper vSRX device. I now need to practice more REGEX to remove all unnecesary output data and be more accurated on what I want to see, like the example above (is still dirty), but the basic goal was achived.

Another challenge that I had at the beginning was to understand the output of that "interfaces = **salt**['net.cli']('show configuration interfaces..." was because I thought every router command line was an item/line inside my list. When saving it in "aaa.txt" file and then printing it, it was printed different from what I had in mind:

This is the file opened by VisualCode (file called aaa.txt):

```
set interfaces ge-0/0/0 description vsrx1_descr_test
set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family inet address 192.168.15.66/24
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family inet sampling input
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family inet sampling output
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family inet dhcp
set interfaces ge-0/0/2 unit 0 family inet address 1.1.1.1/30
set interfaces ge-0/0/2 unit 0 family inet address 192.168.99.1/30
```

This is the file printed by the function:

```
terminal# sudo salt 'vsrx1' red.final
vsrx1:

set interfaces ge-0/0/0 description vsrx1_descr_test
set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family inet address 192.168.15.66/24
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family inet sampling input
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family inet sampling output
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family inet dhcp
set interfaces ge-0/0/2 unit 0 family inet address 1.1.1.1/30
set interfaces ge-0/0/2 unit 0 family inet address 192.168.99.1/30
```

And when changes the SALT function like:

```
interfaces = __salt__['net.cli']('show configuration interfaces | display set', format='xml')['out']['show configuration interfaces | display set']"
to this:
interfaces = __salt__['net.cli']('show configuration interfaces | display set', format='xml')['out']
```

The output was printed vertically, like this:

```
s
e
t

i
n
t
e
r
```

and so on. I broke my head with that one.

Hope this helps. And as always, any correction is welcomed.

Cristian.